# How do I get certificate's key size

Tags: c#, x509certificate2

I have an X.509 certificate and need to get the size of its key (in bits) - e.g., 1024 2048 etc. I have looked at X509Certificate2 and also the bouncycastle X509Certificate classes but can't see how to get the key size.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You surely have access to the public key. The key length is public key's size: `this.PublicKey.Key.KeySize;`
To see an implemented solution, check out [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733772%28VS.90%29.aspx)